# cursor returning more than one record type with same field names

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, database-cursor

Assume 2 tables structured as follows, having a 1:1 row relationship with each other:

```
create table table1 (
  id   number(9)      primary key
 ,name varchar2(100)
);

create table table2 (
  id   number(9)      primary key
 ,name varchar2(100)
);
```

I would like to create a cursor as follows:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is 
            select t1.*
                  ,t2.*
            from table1         t1
                 join table2    t2 on (t2.id = t1.id);
begin
  for r in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.name);     -- here I want to display the table1 name value
  end loop;
end;
```

but of course I get

> ORA-06550: line 8, column 3: PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list
>   of cursor to avoid duplicate column names ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I understand clearly that I am getting this error because **name** is used in both tables and thus the cursor doesn't know which to give me.

I am trying to find out whether there any way to alias an entire record in a cursor to achieve the equivalent of this - likewise not working - code:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is 
            select t1.*  rec1
                  ,t2.*  rec2
            from table1         t1
                 join table2    t2 on (t2.id = t1.id);
begin
  for r in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.rec1.name);     -- have inserted incorrect "rec1" here
  end loop;
end;
```

This theoretically could be expanded to deal with t1,t2,t3...tn tables and records.

For context, my goal here is to reduce the number of composite static record definitions required for individual cursors combining various tables.

Any feedback would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Not possible, you have to give proper aliases

Comment: @KaushikNayak thanks, a pity. Assuming you are correct, my opinion is that there would be significant development benefit to Oracle implementing such an ability. Do you have any thoughts in this regard?

Comment: Well, there could be several features we programmer expect the language should contain for our advantage. You can always request those in the Oracle's forums.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, you have to provide the alias to avoid repetition of same name.
it would have possible if we have the idea how select query works while selecting the same column name from two tables. (because if you select same name from two tables select query adds the alias to it, i am not sure how that works.)